# Using Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

How to use **pending intent** to **Toast something after a specified time when an app closes**? Is there any other ways to do it?

I tried Broadcast receiver but don't know how to proceed.

```
public class Broad extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    i= new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, i, 0);
    Toast.makeText(c, getResultData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

What to do next? Please help. I don't understand the tutorials as I'm new to android.

Comment: many on broadcast receiver and pending intent pal.

Comment: my need is: The app closes, After 10 secs a toast should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
public static void toastInTenSeconds(final Context context, final String text) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000 * 10);
            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it from your `Actvitiy` `onDestroy` or `onStop`.

Comment: onDestroy will cause it to be called at a random time. onStop will cause it to be called in multiple situations. I'd call this function manually when I know the app is about to finish

Comment: You can extend Application, and set it in the manifest, then call this function on the onStop of the Application object.

Comment: OnStop does not exist at the application level :)